# Slow autocomplete in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-2019

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (version 16.0.3) and I have been having serious problems with autocomplete. It is so slow that I type faster than it is able to update, and frequently after I type out a complete and correct language keyword such as `foreach` the autocomplete drop down won't appear until moments before I press space which in many cases causes the keyword `foreach` to be corrected to some nonsense without warning.

This hasn't been a problem for me with any other version of Visual Studio going back to Visual Studio 97, and it is driving me nuts. I have no addons installed.

Is anyone else having this problem, and if so, what if anything were you able to do to resolve it?

Comment: My dropdown appears as soon as I press the letter "f"...running 16.1.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upgrading to 16.1.4 seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: I have 16.10.0 , but the issue remains, extremely slow with auto-completion

Answer (score 1):

You should open window defender then add exclusion folder for visual studio 2019.
I also add my folder source code.
Hope this help to who need

[image: visual studio]

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found that checking out this checkbox speeds ups VisualStudio InteliSence a lot...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXT6A.png)

Comment: Do you  mean "checking" or "unchecking"?